# Is it possible to rename the API Name (Field DeveloperName) of Reports Apex or jsforce?

Tags: apex, metadata-api

It is possible to read reports with Apex with SOQL

```
SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName from Report
```

However it is NOT possible to update such records. I decided to use jsforce in this case and Metadata API to proceed with my changes. I was able to change `Name` by retrieving the report with `conn.metadata.read('Report', [fullNames])` then update the key `name` and pass it to `conn.metadata.update('Report', metadata)`.

But when I decide to change `DeveloperName` I know that `fullName` is composed from `folder.DeveloperName/report.DeveloperName` so if I try to read for the report with the new `DeveloperName` it returns an empty list as the name do not exist.

Is it generally possible to change DeveloperName with APEX or using jsforce? If so, how? I DO NOT need any source code. A short description of the approach is totally sufficient!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Salesforce Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm) from within Apex. Given you know the Report ID from the query, you just need to send a PATCH method to the API. See [Save Changes to Reports](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_save_report.htm#example_save_report). Of course, if you're in Lightning, this might be restricted, so you need to grab a Session ID that supports API access, as outlined in [Making API Calls from Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm#apex_api_calls).

Comment: Our "trick" for Lightning is always the same: a) create a Visualforce Page in addition to the Lightning Compo. b) put the VF into an IFRAME inside the LC c) wire-up a window.sendMessage() communication between LC and VF d) do everything which requires a "full power Session ID" in VF. e) send the results back to the LC via sendMessage() --- Ugly that this is necessary, but serves the purpose. And it works fine with the API you mentioned. Thanks @sfdcfox !!